# .htaccess RewriteRule returns a blank page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to solve this for more than two hours now.
I have a personal site which uses .htaccess to manage urls.
It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
...
RewriteRule ^sklad/?$ index.php?action=sklad
RewriteRule ^sklad/user/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?action=sklad&user=$1
RewriteRule ^sklad/folder/(.+)?$ index.php?action=sklad&folder=$1
RewriteRule ^sklad/file/(.+)?$ engine/ajax/sklad.php?file=$1
RewriteRule ^sklad/logout/?$ index.php?action=sklad&op=logout
...
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php
RewriteRule ^admin/news/?$ admin.php?action=news
```

the first five ones work fine. The **admin/** one works fine. But when I try to access **admin/news/**, I get a blank page. No errors displayed or logged by Apache, and no output. **admin.php?action=news** is working fine.

Both **sklad/** and **admin/** folders physically exist on the server. **BUT** when I rename the admin/ folder to something else **OR** change the the last RewriteRule to something like

```
RewriteRule ^admin123/news/?$ admin.php?action=news
```

I can access **admin123/news/**. If it has something to do with the actual folder existing on the server, then why the first five rules are working? This doesn't make sense.

I'm out of ideas, hope someone here helps...

Comment: Is there a file that starts with `news` in the `/admin/` folder?

Comment: Yes, it's called news.php... I renamed the file and exerything is fine now, thanks! Didn't know about this, pretty unobvious bug (or not?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, it's called news.php... I renamed the file and exerything is fine now, thanks! Didn't know about this, pretty unobvious bug (or not?)

It's not a bug, it sounds like content negotiation (via mod_negotiation) is turned on and it's doing something you don't want. Negotiation can be turned on via a type map or the **MultiViews** option. Typemaps are a little explicit to setup, so I'm assuming since you don't know why this is happening, you haven't set of a specific type that maps to `news.php`. So you've probably got **Multiviews** turned on. You can turn it off by either removing it from an `Options` statement:

```
#  remove this word -----------v
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
```

This could be anywhere, in your htaccess, server config, vhost config, some config include file, etc. So you can also explicitly unset it in your htaccess file (as long as you aren't also explicitly setting it in the same file):

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Added `-Multiviews` to `Options` in my .htaccess, and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not to good with htaccess and RegExp but i think admin/news will fall into your first htaccess rule.

```
   RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php
```

It wont proceed on your second rule on admin which is:

```
   RewriteRule ^admin/news/?$ admin.php?action=news
```

Its the same problem I was facing before.

Try to modify your admin.php, echo/print something when there is no params pass. Something like this:

```
   if($_GET['action'])
   {
        echo 'With Parameters';
   }
   else
   {
       echo 'No Parameters pass';
   }
```

Debugged it that way.

Comment: There's plenty of stuff being shown without any `$_GET['action']` defined - meta, header, the login form (if there's no active session) or welcome page, and footer...