# After setting up RewriteRule in .htaccess, website shows a blank page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'd like to implement the below url rewrite:

`http://www.test.com/folder1/folder2/products`

to

`http://www.test.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?p=products`

Where `folder1` and `folder2` are real directories on the server. The .htaccess I've setup in `folder2` is as below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

However, the website comes out just a blank page without any errors and the Status Code is 200.

I'm sure that the `mod_rewrite` is enabled since there's an another Joomla framework with url rewrite is running properly in other folder.

---

I've referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225088/htaccess-rewriterule-returns-a-blank-page) but it can't help.
I'm really not good in URL rewrite and .htaccess.Thanks for any helps in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some testings, I've solved the issue.

The RewriteRule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```